# How to calculate different between two date()?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

I have two time in this format: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`.
How can I calculate different between these two time?

Comment: Google `php difference two dates`

Comment: one of this times is time of now and other time is time that saved in a session few second ago

Comment: @Pekka I use that but I receive 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $datetime1 = date_create($start);
    $datetime2 = date_create($end);
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    return $interval->format('%a'); //returns the number of days
?>
```

Comment: The answer below has the links to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and the [diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method.